# What is the right way to create a reusable yet flexible form component in JSP/Servlet?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, dry

I'm making my first steps with JSP and servlets, and am building some toy project. I couldn't figure out the right approach to solve the following problem -

In the user management part of the project, there are 3 occasions where user details can be updated:

1. When the user registers to the site (empty registration form)
2. When the user updates own details (form with existing details)
3. When administrator updates user details (form with details and some additional options)

I can think of 3 ways to create these pages:

1. Create a different JSP file for each case, horribly violating the DRY law, but keeping HTML and logic apart.
2. Have a servlet or custom tag generate the form's HTML, in the appropriate way. This means a lot (?) of HTML in the Java code.
3. Place Java logic in a single JSP, which will take care of the form's content according to the context. This means a lot (?) of Java code in the JSP (mostly `if`s, omitting or including fields and values).

What is the common way of solving these problems?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a form, place it in a separate jsp file, and the include it in whichever jsp page you like -

```
<jsp:include page="myForm.jsp"/>
```

This will enable you to re-use the form in any JSP page you like. You will be then reusing the parts that is common to all scenarios.

Comment: The problem is that the form's content (somewhat) depends on the context, so I can't just include it as is. At one case I need an empty form, on another it should contain existing values, and on another more options. But a lot is shared, so it calls for code reuse, but HTML and Java separation is a problem.

Comment: @eran: You can use JSTL for this purpose. Create a bean, assign constants indicating which page is it, and render corresponding parts using JSTL `<c:if...>` or some other conditional tags. You can also show/hide options. You can also choose to populate or not populate an element, i.e., a text box with some pre-existing value in this way. But if the elements are different or you want to render them differently in each page, then you should do so in separate pages.

Comment: from my personal experience I would like separate jsp page which will ensure clean code. If we want to follow Separation of Concern principle then separate jsp page and separate logic might help. @ Sayem what do you think about that?

Comment: @MAK Ripon: The logic that you will be placing in the JSP page is related to the UI of the application. I don't think it's related to any business rules. Enabling/disabling some elements of a form based on some condition which is not related to any business logic probably won't create any cross-cutting concerns in the application. But as I said in the comment, if the components are different, then placing them all in the same page isn't wise.

Comment: @Sayem: all right then. I agree that if components are different then its better to place them in separate jsp pages